# Child class doesn't recognize module imports of parent class?

Tags: python, python-module

I've got two classes in two different modules:

- `animal.py`
- `monkey.py`

**animal.py:**

```
import json

class Animal(object):
    pass
```

**monkey:**

```
import animal

class Monkey(animal.Animal):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Monkey, self).__init__()

        # Do some json stuff...
```

When I try to instantiate a `Monkey`, I get a

```
NameError: global name 'json' is not defined
```

But I'm importing `json` in the defining module of the super class, so why wouldn't it be loaded?

Answer (score 11):

It is loaded, but its name is not available in the scope of `monkey.py`.

You could type `animal.json` to get at it (but why would you), or just type

```
import json
```

in `monkey.py` as well. Python will ensure that the module is not loaded twice.

Comment: So I presume my importing modules into base classes that don't use them is pointless?

Comment: yes, you should only import the modules you use in your file.

Comment: In general I would agree with thebjorn, but sometimes it might be more convenient to reference modules from within another module, eg. when a module bundles a lot of functionality from other modules.

Comment: Just so I'm sure I'm clear: there's no such thing as a global import, correct?

Comment: Mostly correct. This is a language feature to prevent name clashes; for instance, what if my module-level variable has the same name as something that some random module imports? I say "mostly correct", because you could probably write a post-import hook that dynamically adds the newly imported module to the "global" scope of all already imported modules. This is evil; don't do it.

Comment: Another evil thing that you could do, but should not, would be to say `import json; __builtins__.json = json`. I would say this is somewhat less evil than putting the module into every other module's "global" namespace, but it could be a point of debate. But I agree -- don't do stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, python imports do not function as C #include pre-processor directive. They import the module to the namespace of the importing module only and not to the global namespace. So, you're gonna have to import json in each and every module you intend to use it.

Comment: 'to be used by the importing module only' that is not true. See Thomas answer.